# Flash develop debug compiler is not doing File browseForOpen() method

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, flashdevelop

This simple code compiles in Flash develop, but nothing happens:

```
var f:File = new File();
f.browseForOpen("fsd");
```

Comment: What happens? Any error message? Can you post yout full code?

Comment: no errors, the application runs, but doesnt open explorer window, which should open

Answer (score 1):

That code works fine for me in FlashDevelop. Are you certain your project is an AIR app? The File.browseForOpen is only available in AIR: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#browseForOpen%28%29

Alternatively, as their code sample suggests, you could wrap it in a try block and see if you get an error:

```
        try 
        {
            fileToOpen.browseForOpen("Open", [txtFilter]);
            fileToOpen.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected);
        }
        catch (error:Error)
        {
            trace("Failed:", error.message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be to do with the security sandbox.

Try to put browseForOpen inside the MouseEvent.CLICK handler for some button:

```
btn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, browseOpen )

function browseOpen( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    f.browseForOpen("fsd");
}
```